# How can I store data from API in ajax variable while api changing data each sec?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created ajax on real-time **RESTful API** which has JSON formatted data. Every sec. data values are changed.

How can I change background color fading if the data value current value is more than the last second value?

Herein, my ajax code with API world markets:

```js
setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"get",
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            url:"http://www.yourtradelog.com/liveapi/world-markets",
            data:{"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(res){
                if(!res){
                    alert('Something went wrong')
                }else{
                    $('#sensex').text(res.sensex.lastprice);

                    if(res.sensex.lastprice > 0){
                        console.log("green");
                        document.getElementById("chg").className = "greenText";
                    }
                    else{
                        document.getElementById("chg").className = "redText";
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    },1000);
```

```css
div {
        transition: background 0.5s linear;
    }

    .greenText {
        background-color: rgb(83, 241, 83);
    }
    .redText {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div id="chg">Test</div>
    
     
                                     <a id="sensex" ></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect can be achieved with CSS and a [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) animation

> Transitions enable you to define the transition between two states of an element. Different states may be defined using pseudo-classes like :hover or :active or dynamically set using JavaScript.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  document.body.className = (document.body.className === "flash" ? "" : "flash");
}, 2000);
```

```css
body { transition: background 0.5s linear; }
.flash { background-color: yellow; }
```

---

Now we need a way to detect that the current value is bigger than the previous one. For this we can use the [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) where we can store the current value, which is then the "old" value on the next round.

*(more or less pseudo code)*

```js
var output = $("#sensex"),
    oldValue = output.data("oldValue") || 0;
    // get the "old" value or zero if there hasn't been an "old" value yet

/*...*/

output.data("oldValue", res.sensex.lastprice);
// store the current value in "oldValue" for the next round

/*...*/

if (res.sensex.lastprice > oldValue) {
  // change background color
}
```

---

If we combine both steps we have something like this for the `success` handler:

```js
var output = $("#sensex"),
    oldValue = output.data("oldValue") || 0;

output[0].className = "";

output.text(res.sensex.lastprice)
      .data("oldValue", res.sensex.lastprice)
      .addClass(res.sensex.lastprice > 0 ? "greenText" : "redText");

if (res.sensex.lastprice > oldValue) {
    output.addClass("flash");
}
```

And this for the CSS *(reduced example)*:

```css
#chg { transition: background 0.5s linear }
.flash { background-color: yellow }
.greenText { color: green }
.redText { color: red }
```

Example as snippet:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  getNewValue()
    .then(function(res) {
        var output = $("#sensex"),
            oldValue = output.data("oldValue") || 0;

        output[0].className = "";

        output.text(res.sensex.lastprice)
              .data("oldValue", res.sensex.lastprice)
              .addClass(res.sensex.lastprice > 0 ? "greenText" : "redText");

        if (res.sensex.lastprice > oldValue) {
          output.addClass("flash");
        }
    });
}, 2000);


/* fake api call */
function getNewValue() {
  return $.Deferred().resolve({
    sensex: {
        lastprice: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) * (Math.random() > .5 ? 1 : -1)
    }
  }).promise();
}
```

```css
#sensex { transition: background 0.5s linear }
.flash { background-color: yellow }
.greenText { color: green }
.redText { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sensex"></div>
```

Example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h8k1ar5z/

Comment: Should I not require to store variable last second value?.... How can understand my code that current second value is more than last second?

Comment: @KINNARI I've modified my answer

Comment: Ok let me try your answer. thanks in advanced @Andreas

Comment: error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null`

Comment: Even with all the changes you've made to the code this error can only occur when there's no element with the id `chg`

Comment: yes you was right.. now i got price but only green... right now nasdaq is live but.. color is green.. nothing changing in it, Real time `res.nasdaq.lastprice`

Comment: I've modified my example to use jQuery which makes it a little bit easier. Did you adjust the code to use `nasdaq` instead of `sensex`?

Comment: yes i am using nasdaq because its live now changing rate. @

Comment: _"Did you adjust the code to use `nasdaq` instead of `sensex`?"_. Also check the console for errors.

Comment: yes i adjusted in code as nasdaq ... value is live but yellow.. only yellow not changing

Comment: there is not error in console... api giving live rate